# Why can't I see the result of a boolean modifier until I apply it?

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

Is it the case that the modifiers don't work "in the same way" ? For instance if I intersect a cube with a cylinder and choose a Boolean difference modifier to it, I can't see the result (i.e. the hole in the cube) until I 'apply' the modification.

Alternately, If I revolve a circle using the screw modifier and change the screw property to a non-zero value I see the result of the modifier straight away (i.e. I see a helix).  I've read elsewhere that some people don't apply their modifiers often if at all. However I find that unless I apply them, other things such as physics won't work properly until the modifiers on objects are applied.

Am I thinking about this the right way? The reason for asking is that there is no way to go back and change a modifier once it's applied which can be problematic unless one saves a lot of different versions in a workflow.

Comment: You can't really see the result of a *Boolean* modifier if the original object is in the way of the transformation, occupying the space that was removed from the other object. [See my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66716/how-to-create-a-half-turn-staircase/66718#66718) for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Duarte Farrajota Ramos - I did consider that but when I moved the intersecting solid out of the way there was no hole to be seen until I apply the modifier, I'm starting to think I'm asking a question that has no real answer. Maybe that's just how that particular modifier works. As I say, I'm just a beginner. BTW what do you use to make the video parts of the answer in your link (should that be a separate question??)

Comment: That is how the modifier is supposed to work, it keeps the transformation 'live' and interactive. If you move the object the hole moves with it. Otherwise what would be the pint of being a modifier in the first place? If you want it static then apply the modifier and be done with it.

Comment: That question would be offtopic here, it's not about Blender. The software is [ScreenToGIF](https://github.com/NickeManarin/ScreenToGif)