# How to make spiral stairs

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

Im making a water tank and to its side i want to make spiral stairs. I have tried 2 method but did not work for me both. I have add a spiral curve so that a single stair can rotate along the curve with the dupliframes. Then i added a array modifier and empty to control. I got this result the stairs not matching the side walls. And i want the result of the curve rotating in that way i want my stairs to be curved. Any suggestion

**New result with empty**
[image]

**With screw modifier result**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66716/how-to-create-a-half-turn-staircase

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i have update the new result as per the link but not get the result what i need. I have a curve in my model i want that way it should take 3-4 turns. And here im getting just a single turn. and side railing also not align perfect

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos i have added the screw modifier the curve result i have got but the stairs not going up and down. For that what can i do any suggestion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A suggestion is to use the *Screw modifier* for the railing walls & keep the array for the steps. You can control the height of the screw with an empty and the diameter either by scaling in object or edit mode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying with the railing and stairs merge with single mesh can i make the screw modifier instead of doing manually with empty

Comment: The screw modifier would deform the steps - which is why I kept it separate. You can eventually 'Apply'  and join the meshes if necessary.

Comment: can you plz send me the file how you have control im not getting the same result you have

Comment: Done. If you extend the spiral up more - you will have to adjust the z-height of the steps.

Comment: having problem again with the stairs i have posted the question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78333/how-to-align-steps