# How to align steps

Tags: mesh

Im making a curve steps and with the reference of this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/how-to-make-spiral-stairs) i able to make the wall and the stairs. I have align the stairs but the problem is i want to increase the height of the stairs as its look smaller. When i move the empty in z axis all the alignment above the stairs get disturb. Is there any trick or suggestion i can make align my stairs or if other method plz. Thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: A shallow ramp has shallow stairs. Think about how it works in real life. If you want your steps higher, you can raise the steepness of the ramp. You could try make the steps deeper, but that can only help so much.

Comment: @Patdog can you explain what to do in this condition not working. Little bit detail explanation  Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is really a Blender question. Maybe use a resource like http://www.firstinarchitecture.co.uk/how-to-calculate-stairs/