# Why is the array modifier scaling my object?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to practice using the array modifier by creating a ring and having a series of gems that wrap around the surface. I created an empty in the centre of the ring that would serve as a pivot point, but when I clicked object offset (which I assume is the correct thing to do?) it created copies that became progressively more massive. What have I done incorrectly?[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object and your empty have different scale values. Hover over your object's scale values and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, then select the empty, hover over its X scale value and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. Repeat for Y and Z (provided your object is uniformly scaled).

Alternatively: Select your empty, then shift-select your object, rightclick on the scale values and say: copy to selected.

Any differences of rotation, location or scale between the two objects get multiplied for each new copy. That can be pretty powerful.

[image]

Two array modifiers on top of each other. The empties just differ a bit in scale, rotation and location.