# Snap to vertex projection while sliding an edge

Tags: modeling, snapping

I have made a staircase by creating a simple mesh with two faces per step. The general volume of the stair is a rectangle as visible in the top-left editor. Then I extruded the top of each vertical face horizontally to create a small overhang for each step (see bottom left editor below).

When extruding along the normal of the vertical face, the added face doesn't match anymore with the general rectangle limits, there is some variable inner/outer offset (as visible for the selected edge).

I now need to adjust the overhanging corners. Each vertical edge must be slid to a vertical position given by the overall rectangle.

[image]

I can likely create a customized orientation for each step and then snap without using the slide operator, but that seems very inefficient.

I have two questions:

- About the slide operator: Is there a possibility to snap to the external rectangle?
- About the method itself: Is there a better method than using the slide operator?

Comment: You can't snap when edge sliding. There seem to be far more modular approaches to this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66716/how-to-create-a-half-turn-staircase

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: This is possible to use the same stair model for an helical staircase, but not in my case where each step is unique. I hope some approach still exists, as it took me a lot of time to align the extruded face corners (mostly using the knife tool, possibly a noob's choice...).