# How to let an array curve around tiled spiral, without rotation to the floor plane? Trying to create a tilted spiral staircase using array and curve

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I'm trying to create a spiral staircase that follows a **tiled and tapered spiral**, as shown in the image below. With the existing controls in the `array` modifier and `curve` modifier, I could only create a normal spiral staircase, with the spiral axis being vertical. I want to let the staircase steps array to follow a tilted spiral array that I prepared, but the curve object distorts. (See second image)

Any ideas on how I can let the staircase follow the tilted spiral, **while the each of the step remains parallel to the ground in the arrangement**?

I tried using animation nodes, but the results didn't look pretty because of geometry overlaps. Using the array modifier creates a prettier mesh, thus the result looked much better.

You can find the Blender file here (Animation nodes version also included, for reference):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jDKfNAtaC8c0cGF0UnB5vcz44Gb6YTNS/view?usp=sharing

Thank you!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, take a look a this question, also read the comments as the solution can be simplified: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve/165691#165691

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66716/how-to-create-a-half-turn-staircase https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve